# How to extract the tags associated with Cursor location

Tags: javascript

How to extracts the Tags associated with the cursor location. 
In the below HTML example, when my cursor is at "associated", i want to get the information about which all tags are added to the text "associated".

```
<html>
<body>
How <b>to <font color="#FF000">extract<i> the tags associated with </i>Cursor </b>location</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i want to get "b , font, i"

Is it possible to get this information.

Comment: Do you mean the regular cursor rather than the caret in an editable document? When do you want this information (i.e. which event are you intending to handle)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I'm assuming you're talking about the regular cursor rather than a caret.

You could do something like this:

```
var lastElementEntered = null;

document.onmouseover = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    lastElementEntered = e.target || e.srcElement;
};

document.onmouseout = function() {
    lastElementEntered = null;
}

function getCursorElementPath() {
    var tagNames = [];
    if (lastElementEntered) {
        var node = lastElementEntered;
        while (node && node != document.body) {
            tagNames.unshift(node.nodeName);
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }
    return tagNames;
}

alert( getCursorElementPath() );
```